# Does the logical operator || executes both sides before returning one side

Tags: javascript, constructor, return, apply, logical-operators

I have created my own `new` function.

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
this.firstName = firstName;  
this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {  
console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName)
}

function spawn(constructor) {
var obj = {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, constructor.prototype)
var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
return constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1)) || obj

}

var crockford = spawn(Person, "Douglas", "Crockford")
crockford.getName();
```

I am just confused about the  operation of the logical operator ||.

`constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1)) || obj`  it seams that javascript engine first executes the left side of the code even it being falsy (means apply function is applied to constructor before returning obj) and then return the right side of the || operator. am i right? Consider the code below,

`var app = constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))
return app || obj`

in this case the `constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))` is already applied to the constructor.it doesn't rely one the return value of logical operator.

I  just want the clarification that does || operator executes both sides of the function before returning one or it just select one and the other one is not even executed.. i think it executes `constructor.apply(obj, myArray.slice(1))` that why i am getting the result **Douglas Crockford**.

Comment: I guess you could always just read the [*language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-binary-logical-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

The right hand side of either the '&&' and '||' logical operators will only be evaluated and returned if the left hand side is 'falsey' and 'truthy' respectively.

The left hand side will always be evaluated.

[MDN Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking for `A operator B == true`:

-In case of logical `OR`, the second operand is evaluated only if the first operand evaluates to false (0)

-In case of `AND`, the second operand is evaluated only if the first operand evaluates to true (1).

Comment: so the first part will effect the code even being falsy?

Comment: If you are checking for `A or B == true` and A is evaluated to true then your B won't be checked because The overall condition has already become true.

Comment: But doesn't the || operator works like a selector(it has to choose one code of these two)?

Comment: No, read what is written. If the first returns true then the second is not evaluated. If the first returns false, the second is unequivocally evaluated and its value returned, whether it's "truthy" or "falsey".

Comment: So the first part will also effect the code and even after being falsy it has the effect on the code and just not checked and left behind?

Answer (score 0):

Both `||` and `&&` operators checks

1. only LHS if result is sufficient to guess the whole result ( i.e `true` in case of `||`, and `false` in case of `&&`).
2. checks both LHS and RHS if result of LHS is not sufficient to guess whole result. ( if LHS for `||` is `false` or LHS of `&&` is `true`, then it checks for RHS also).